# How to change button text to font awesome icon using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome

I have a button `<button class="home-signup-button button-add" formnovalidate>Sign up</button>`

On click of this button I want to change the text from Sign up to a font awesome icon. `<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i>`. So far I've tried

```
$(".home-signup-button.button-add").click(function(){
    $(this).text("<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i>");
});
```

But I get an error that reads `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. If I just put in some text like "Connecting..." instead of the font awesome it works without any error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

instead of `.text()` use `.html()`

Answer (score 3):

This is my code, How I would do

```
$(".home-signup-button.button-add").click(function(){
        $('#change').html("<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i>");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to do the following:

```
$(".home-signup-button.button-add").click(function(){
    $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i>");
});
```

You could also do this:

```
$(".home-signup-button.button-add").click(function(){
    $(this).append($('i').addClass('fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'));
});
```